# Can I run jdk commands in an android application?

Tags: java, android, jarsigner

I'm trying to make an app that can validate other apks using jarsigner from JDK. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. To run JDK commands on the Android, you would need JDK installed on the Android. But you can't install it because no runtime exists for the Android (or the iOS for that matter.)

Comment: No runtime exists..bummer. My only hope now is that the android installer verifies the apk itself automatically.

Comment: In a way, your device already does this. However, if I understand your end-game correctly, I don't think you're going to have much luck. You may find some additional helpful info here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/how-can-i-verify-the-authenticity-of-an-apk-file-i-downloaded (See the top answer.)

Comment: Yeah that post is the best thing I've found as well. It would require me to upload the entire apk to a server to verify it. I was hoping to just pass up the certificate, signature and manifest and verify locally once those have been checked.