Unable to Execute OpenJDK Binary on Android 11: "Permission Denied" Error
I am developing an Android application where I need to execute the java binary from an extracted OpenJDK 22 package. The Java binary is located in my app's external files directory (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.newproject31/files/jdk-22.0.2/bin/java) and in (/data/data/com.newproject31/files/jdk -22.0.2/bin/java). However, when I try to execute the binary to check java version through java -version using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() , I encounter a "Permission Denied" error.
Extracted OpenJDK: I extracted the OpenJDK package to my app's external files directory.
Tried to Execute: I attempted to run the
command /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.newproject31/files/jdk-22.0.2/bin/java -version and /data/data/com.my.newproject31/files/jdk-22.0.2/bin/java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec().
Permission Denied: Every time I run the command, I get the following error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.newproject31/files/jdk-22.0.2/bin/java": error=13,Permission denied
Checked Permissions: I have read/write permissions for this directory, but it seems Android does not allow executing binaries from external storage due to scoped storage restrictions introduced in Android 11.
Is there a way to execute binaries, like the java binary from OpenJDK, within an Android app on Android 11?
Android Version: 11
Target SDK: 30

Which OpenJDK distribution and version package did you extract? And for which operating system and architecture it was?

Openjdk version:22.0.2, operating system: linux, architecture:aarch64.

I don't believe that there is a certainty that linux executables will run on Android. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959239/can-i-include-linux-executables-in-my-android-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105645/can-i-run-jdk-commands-in-an-android-application. Instead I recommend you should ask the actual problem that you are trying to resolve using the JDK inside Android so people can offer other solutions.

I want to compile java codes and real time auto completions using jdk.

Shared storage aka /storage/emulated/0 is mounted in a way that makes all files on it non-executable. If you want to execute something save it in the app-private directory /data/data/<packagename> at least on Android 11 it should be possible to execute somethin there. Note that Standard Linux Java binaries won't work on Android because of problems with certain standard libraries.

Why do you want to use Android as a development studio instead of a PC?
